# Why isn't curl working with my TLS ngrok tunnel?

Tags: apache, ssl, curl, ngrok

When I run `curl --insecure 'https://foo.ngrok.io/page'` on my TLS tunnel to my Apache IP-based virtual host, I get a "400 Bad Request" response saying "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand...Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port...Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please."

However if I use curl to make a request directly to my localhost address e.g. `curl --insecure 'https://foo/page'` I get the correct response. Also, if I make a request in a browser to `https://foo.ngrok.io/page` I get the correct response.

I'm running: OS X 10.9.5, Apache 2.4, ngrok2, and curl 7.43.0. My SSL certificate is self-signed.

What I noticed from my access log is that when I use curl on `foo.ngrok.io` is that the my `HTTP/1.1` requests are changed to `HTTP/1.0` requests. Also, here's the corresponding relevant bits from my error log:

```
ssl_engine_kernel.c(1824): [client 127.0.0.2:50517] OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
[client 127.0.0.2:50517] AH01996: SSL handshake failed: HTTP spoken on HTTPS port; trying to send HTML error page
SSL Library Error: error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request -- speaking HTTP to HTTPS port!?
protocol.c(616): [client 127.0.0.2:50517] Request received from client: GET / HTTP/1.0
http_filters.c(1042): [client 127.0.0.2:50517] Response sent with status 400, headers:
```

**Apache Virtual Host Configuration**

```
Listen 127.0.0.2:443
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:443>
        ServerName foo
        DocumentRoot /Users/me/site
        ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/foo_error_log"
        CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/foo_access_log" common
        <Directory "/Users/me/site">
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
                Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
        <IfModule ssl_module>
                SSLEngine on
                <Directory "/Users/me/site">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
                SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/ssl/foo.key"
                SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/ssl/foo.crt"
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache SSL Configuration**

```
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/usr/local/var/run/apache2/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
```

**ngrok.yml Configuration**

```
authtoken: <omitted>
tunnels:
  foo:
    addr: 127.0.0.2:443
    proto: tls
    hostname: "foo.ngrok.io"
```

Comment: Note: the real problem isn't so much that I can't use curl, it's that services that I use ngrok for to make webhooks are having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, a HTTP client (curl, browser, etc) must support SNI in order to communicate with ngrok over HTTPS. This implicates both TLS and HTTP ngrok tunnels.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding -k after your curl command. For example:

curl https://www{domain}com.ngrok.io/webhook -k